# how to sync core data icloud with ios and macOs app

Tags: core-data, synchronization, icloud

I'm developping an iPad application that uses CoreData with iCloud. It works great!
I'm able to open  ~/Library/Mobile Documents" with the folder that matches my  Team ID and iCloud container.
I'm making also a macOS app that needs to access the iCloud.  In macOS app, I added the iOS app container ID. So i have two container ID: ca.company.MacContainerID and   ca.company.IPadContainerID which works for iPad app.

When i execute the following code in MacOS app, URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: returns nil.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *containerID =  @"A1B2C3E4F5.ca.company.IPadContainerID";
NSURL *url = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:containerID];    
url is nil
```

I don't know what to do to access to iCloud with core data inside from iPad app.
Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I was building the Mac application with an iOS provisionning file. So i put a Mac provisioning and it works; URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier return me a non nul value.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a problem with your `containerID`. Did you double-check the ID string?